# Error - Visual studio 2017 community with C# language using zeroMQ cannot find libzmq or libsodium

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-7, zeromq

Using VS2017 Community, up to date, on Win7, up to date, using the nuget zeroMQ package "Install-Package ZeroMQ -Version 4.1.0.27" for project, on creating the hwclient C# program compilation is successful as a windows form.

On running it  - get error that zeroMQ.lib cannot find libzmq.dll, or that libzmq.dll is not a valid windows dll, and that also libsodium.dll cannot also be found. The error is trapped within zeroMQ.dll when a ZContext is required.

The project uses a nuget package ZeroMQ alone so DO NOT have access to other resources, else whats the point of having a tidy nuget package for it (that is not the question - just how do you resolve the missing dll's problem)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ZeroMQ;
namespace InterComm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string strHostName = "";
            strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
            IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
            IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
            lblMyIPString.Text = addr[1].ToString();
        }
        private void btnHello_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string endpoint = "tcp://" + tbTheirIP.Text + ":5555";
            using (var context = new ZContext()) <- ERROR
            {
                using (var requester = new ZSocket(context, SocketType.REQ))
                {
                    requester.Connect(endpoint);
                    for (int n = 0; n < 3; ++n)
                    {
                        string requestText = "Hello";
                        rtbResponse.Text.Insert(0, "Sending... " + requestText);
                        requester.Send(new ZFrame(requestText));
                        using (ZFrame reply = requester.ReceiveFrame())
                        {
                            string resp = reply.ReadString();
                            if (resp.Length == 0)
                            {
                                rtbResponse.Text.Insert(0, "Silence from : "+ lblTheirIP.Text); 
                            }
                                else
                            {
                                rtbResponse.Text.Insert(0, "Received: " + reply.ReadString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and finally

```
InterComm.exe Warning: 0 : UnmanagedLibrary[libsodium] Unable to extract the 
EmbeddedResource "ZeroMQ.libsodium.i386.dll" to 
"C:\Users\techuser\AppData\Local\Temp\ZeroMQ.libsodium.i386.dll".
InterComm.exe Warning: 0 : UnmanagedLibrary[libzmq] Unable to extract the EmbeddedResource "ZeroMQ.libzmq.i386.dll" to "C:\Users\techuser\AppData\Local\Temp\ZeroMQ.libzmq.i386.dll".
Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in ZeroMQ.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in ZeroMQ.dll
The type initializer for 'ZeroMQ.lib.zmq' threw an exception.
```

Comment: Have you tried using NetMQ? Haven't had this problem with it

Comment: What are the project settings?  Are you using X86 and AnyCPU?  It appears it is looking for a 386 dll which is old.  I don't think you can call a 386 dll directly from c#.  You must call a c++ wrapper to execute a 386 dll.  So the zeroMQ package must be calling a c++ wrapper and then which is calling the dll  that is giving the exception.

Comment: BradleyDotNet - yes, also tried NetMQ and same problem at same point.

Comment: jdweng - On VS2017 it no longer spreads out the dlls as you specify the target platform - I normally target x86 only, but have also tried AnyCPU, x64 and x86 same effect. The '386', x86, amd64 are VS internal search patterns: even acquired dll's from elsewhere, depends.exe checked, placed in the early directories and regsvr32'ed it still fails to see them. The whole point of the zeroMQ nuget C# is that the C++ calls have been wrapped in C# - as per the zeroMQ documentation and examples.  Its the extract/missing dll's that is the problem.

Comment: NetMQ cannot yield the same problem as it is not using libzmq, it is a pure port of zeromq to c#.
When using NetMQ you cannot use the same code, as it is a different library that is compatible with zeromq

Comment: Please look: Try nuget.org/packages/ZeroMQ/v4.1.0.30, I've made some changes to the library.

Comment: Have found that Microsoft in its infinite wisdom partially updated VS2017 to a 'Tablet Form Only' compile (I do everything from embedded low level to monolith programs in VS, targeting x86, x64, ARM etc) whereby prior Desktop creations also became 'ill'. While the ZeroMQ aspect will now be ignored and forgiven (but only in this VS2017 development environment), the NetMQ aspect will be used as post MS latest update it now works!